# Converting a vuejs configuration to nuxt 2 config

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

In vue.js I get the next config and I need to convert it to use in Nuxt2.x.

```js
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('babel-loader')
      .test(/\.js|jsx$/)
      .use('babel-loader')
      .loader('babel-loader')
      .end()

    config.resolve.alias.set('cornerstone-wado-image-loader', 'cornerstone-wado-image-loader/dist/dynamic-import/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.min.js')
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/cornerstone-wado-image-loader/dist/dynamic-import'),
            to: DIST_DIR,
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
}
```

I have tried in Nuxt config something as below, but it doesn't work and I don't know where I put the "alias resolve" portion.

And when I do `nuxt run dev`, the browse console shows:

```
"http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/index.worker.min.worker.js"  -- script not found
```

This script is into "node_modules/cornerstone-wado-image-loader/dist/dynamic-import"

Here is the `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    
build: {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: './node_modules/cornerstone-wado-image-loader/dist/dynamic-import',
        to:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? DIST_DIR 
            : './_nuxt',
      },
    ]),
  ],
},
```

Comment: This is usually where you make some additions to Webpack: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extend

Comment: @kissu  I know, but It´s not clear how I can solve my case with that docs